# Chrome Postman vs jQuery

Tags: ajax, postman

I'm testing a WebSEAL secured RESTful service against Chrome Postman which works 100%. I pass in basic authentication credentials as required and send the request.

There is no authorization prompt in the browser, and the response returns the expected results without error.

However, when I try to do this in jQuery and run it via a browser, I get nowhere, exception CORS errors and other authorization 401 errors that I am not expecting.

In my opinion, Postman generates exactly the same XMLHttpRequest string that I would via any AJAX framework in JavaScript, yet Postman succeeds and normal JavaScript does not.

What is the difference here? I am completely at a lost.

```
// jQuery
var authorization = basic_auth('username', 'password1'),
    url = 'https://url.domain.name/service.svc';


$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    beforeSend: function (req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authorization);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');                
    },
    success: function (s) {

    }
});

// XMLHttpRequest
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    authorization = basic_auth('username', 'password1'),
    url = 'https://url.domain.name/service.svc';
xml.open('GET', url, true);
xml.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authorization);
xml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xml.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', 1000);
xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
    xhrResult(httpRequest);
};        
xml.send(null);
```

**UPDATE & RESOLUTION**

Chrome, by default, does not allow XS-XHR from localhost.

Comment: How did you enable this for localhost?

Comment: @snowman4415 in Google Chrome, you cannot. Your only option is to disabled web security for Chrome during development. Take note that this disables all security features in the browser until you restart it. CORS in other browsers are untested, however, so I cannot guide you on that.

Comment: you can use extensions like this one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi to enable / disable CORS in chrome